# What's the easiest way to get the dates of the beginning and end of the month?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Below is the best way I have found.  Thoughts?  If you load this up and run is there a faster way to get it to load then what I have done here? Is there anything I am missing?

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetMonthStart(DateTime.Now));
    Console.WriteLine(GetMonthEnd(DateTime.Now));
}
private DateTime GetMonthStart(DateTime dt)
{
    dt= dt.Date;
    return dt.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(dt.Day - 1));
}
private DateTime GetMonthEnd(DateTime dt)
{
    dt= dt.Date;
    return GetMonthStart(dt).AddMonths(1).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1));
}
```

Comment: A question asking for opinions is not suitable to the StackExchange format. Please read our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: You might want to ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This seems cleaner for first day: pass the target date into dateTime: new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if better, but I would probably do

```
private DateTime GetMonthStart(DateTime dt)
{
    return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);
}

private DateTime GetMonthEnd(DateTime dt)
{
    return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month));
}
```

Comment: This would be ideal for an extension method on DateTime